# Django Model Creating with Verbose Name

Tags: django, django-models

When creating a model object, can you use the verbose name to create? I have a model that has a dot in the name and I cannot have dot in a variable name.

file.xls

```
|---------|-----------------------|
|  Start  | ExonicFunc.UHNCLGGene |
|---------|-----------------------|
| 2488153 |   nonsynonymous SNV   |
| 3301721 |     synonymous SNV    |
|---------|-----------------------|
```

models.py

```
class Variant(models.Model):
    start = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    exonic_function = models.CharField(verbose_name="ExonicFunc.UHNCLGGene", max_length=20, null=True)
```

view.py

```
def upload(request):
    # reads file.xls
    raw_data = pandas.read_excel(request.FILES.get("file"))
    
    for _, row in raw_data.iterrows():
        variant = Variant.objects.create(**row)
```

Comment: Please add some code to help others understand what you mean.

Comment: Hey welcome here please share code with us then we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`verbose_name` is just a label for your field in admin panel. You probably want to use `db_column`

```
exonic_function = models.CharField(db_column="ExonicFunc.UHNCLGGene", max_length=20, null=True)
```

and they assign value in your view as usual

```
variant.exonic_function = "bla"
```